# cordova error when adding any platform

Tags: cordova

When I try to add any platform to my Apache Cordova project or even just listing them it gives me the following error:

```
path.js:424
var path = (i >= 0) ? arguments[i] : process.cwd();
                                             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd
at Error (native)
at Object.posix.resolve (path.js:424:50)
at Function.Module._resolveLookupPaths (module.js:263:17)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:330:31)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:40:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that your not at cordova project file. You should change your directory to the root of your project. tell me if it works with you.

Comment: No. That didn't help me. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Do u have already a platform folder ?? If so delete it and then try to add it again.

Comment: Please can u post an image of your folder structure ?? And how you command to add platform from command line ?

Comment: Okay, so deleting my platform folder helped me.